# How do I get the index of frame in a animation

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm currently making a game with SpriteKit in Swift, and using animateWithTextures() to make animation for different move. Now my question is how do I get the index of current frame in a animation before it ends?
The reason why I need to get the ID is because sometimes I need to cancel an action before it finished but not too early. For example, I have a action contain 10 frames, player can cancel that action only after frame 6? Also I might use the frame later for check the animation's process as well.

Comment: I can't find it right now on SO,  I have answered this before, but there is no way to determine the frame that it is on natively.  You need to either create a custom `SKAction`, or override I think the `texture` property to determine what texture is being shown

Comment: How to get the current texture or its name? Or is there other way to get more control on the duration of animation? There should be much more than just check start or complete in an animation that programmers would need to do and SpriteKits developers would aware of, right?

Comment: self.texture,  you cant get it's name, you would have to compare the texture.  As to your second question, animateWithTextures is just an array,  and everything that is done is black boxed to keep things simple.  That is why we have custom animations, for the advance features that you would need

Comment: Can't we get the texture's filename? Have tried to use print(myTexture) and get the result : Optional (" <SKTexture> \'filename.png\' (100 x 100)"). But still can't find the way to just get the "filename.png".

Comment: maybe you use textures differently than I do,  I use an atlas

Comment: I'm using an atlas too. But an atlas is a set of textures anyway. So the problem is still need to find out how to get the texture's name isn't it? Thinking about to use extension or property observer. Still got no clue.

Comment: I just looked at SKTexture header file,  there is no public access to the name, so it must be internal only.  Finding the name of the texture is easy,  In your loading phase, you create a dictionary of `<SKTexture,String>` (I can't remember, but I believe doing it this way passes the key by reference) Then when you need to grab the name, just do `let name = dictionary[self.texture]`.  If you are going through all this problem though, it is a lot easier just to make a custom action that keeps count of the frame, and changes the texture to the next iteration in the array

Comment: Thats a good idea! Thanks very much. By the way, how to make a custom action that you think is easier for this case? Could you please give me a simple example?

Comment: I dont have an example, but if you create a new file, look under resources,  there is something called SpriteKit Action.  That is what you need to make custom actions

Comment: Maybe this can help. http://cartoonsmart.com/composing-skactions-in-xcode-7-story-tellers-ios-starter-kit-documentation/

Comment: Perhaps you should subclass `SKTexture` to add an index value to the animation textures that you can check during the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
        if String(yourSprite.texture).rangeOfString("frameImageName") != nil {
            //code to stop animation 
            }
```

So if you put this piece of code inside the update function the frames get checked every time the function gets called and you can easily stop the animation at the right point.